# Using awk with variable

Tags: linux, awk

I am using this awk command to extract three rows from a text file.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS=","}; {print $1,$3,$10}' $FILENAME > $OUTPUT
```

I wish to specify the column numbers as a variable separately so it will be easier to modify in the future like this:

```
COLUMNS=$1,$3,$10
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS=","}; {print $COLUMNS}' $FILENAME > $OUTPUT
```

However it pulls all columns into the output, not only the 3 I specified. How do I do this properly?

Comment: Your trapped by the shell quoting necessities/rules/limits. Try `echo $COLUMNS` and start getting enlightened. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

like this ?

```
$ more file
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5

$ a='$1,$2,$NF'

$ awk -F, "{print $a}" file
a b e
1 2 5
```

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: The proposal works. So why doesn't this answer the OP's question please?